# how to clone heroku app which was created by button and now dont have access to that button

Tags: git, heroku, clone, heroku-cli

few months back i deployed a web app on heroku using heroku deploy button, now i want to clone that app and deploy it to another account because i have lost access to that repo from which i had deployed that app.

so when i search for cloning, i came to know that i can clone app which was deployed using CLI commands, but deployed from github or using button cant be cloned.

i also tried heroku slugs:download -a APP_NAME command but not successful.

So please help me to get the entire app and code so that i can deploy it to another account.

Answer (score 0):

First download and install heroku CLI.

Then run this command:

```
heroku login
```

Login by using your username and password.

Then git clone by using:

```
heroku git:clone -a NAME-OF-YOUR-APP
```

**** OR ****

1. Login to heroku : https://id.heroku.com/
2. select your app.
3. Select Deploy option.

Here you will get all the details with commands for getting the source code.